# Proving that $\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}:\lVert \vec{x}\rVert\ge 1 \}$ is closed

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology

To prove that  $\{\vec{x}\in\mathbb{R}:\lVert \vec{x} \rVert\ge 1 \}$ is closed, I need to use the following definition of a closed set:

> Let $V$ be a normed vector space. A set $S\subseteq V$ is closed iff it contains all its limit points.

In my understanding, I need to show that if $\exists \vec{x}\in V$ such that a sequence $\{\vec{x}_n\}$ contained entierely in $S$ converges to $\vec{x}$, and $\vec{x}\not\in S$, then $\exists \varepsilon>0$ such that $n>N_\varepsilon >0$ implies $x_n\not\in S$, a contradiction. However, I have no idea  how to do this.

Would appreciate some help.

Comment: if $\|x_n\| \ge 1$ then $\inf_n \|x_n\| \ge 1$ so that $x =\lim_n x_n$,  $\|x\| \ge 1$

Comment: You need to prove that for $(x_n)\to x$ then $\|x\|\ge 1$

Comment: @user1952009, if $\lVert x_n \rVert\ge 1$ then $\lim_n \lVert x_n \rVert = \lVert x \rVert < 1$. Why do you think it's not true?

Comment: @sequence again : by definition of the convergence of a sequence, or the open-ness/closed-ness of a set

Comment: @user1952009, can you please elaborate? Is it true that $\lim_n \lVert x_n\rVert = \lVert x \rVert$?

Comment: What is the definition of $(x_n)_n$ converges ?

Comment: I'm not sure what $(x_n)_n$ means.

Comment: @sequence the definition of "the sequence $x_n$ converges". In a normed vector space $V,\|.\|$ , the definition is that there exists some $x \in V$ such that $\lim_{x \to \infty}\|x-x_n\| = 0$. It is also by definition (of the topology on $V$) that the set $\{ x \in V, \|x -a\| < r\}$ is open, so that the complementary set $\{ x \in V, \|x -a\| \ge r\}$ is closed

Answer (score 2):

It follows from the reverse triangle inequality 
$$|\;||x||-||y||\;|\leq ||x-y||$$
that the norm is continuous, hence if $\{x_n\}$ is a sequence with $||x_n||\geq 1$ for all $n$ and $x_n\to x$, then
$$ ||x||=\lim_{n\to\infty}||x_n||\geq 1$$

Comment: Sorry, this is not clear at all.

Comment: Which part is not clear?

Comment: Why you would need a "reverse triangle inequality". It is true also in a metric space where we don't have such an inequality.

Comment: 1. What does it mean that a norm is continuous?
2. How does
$$ ||x||=\lim_{n\to\infty}||x_n||\geq 1$$ follow from this inequality?

Comment: @sequence the norm of the limit is the limit of the norms

Comment: @user1952009: yes you do. If $d$ is the metric, then $|d(x,y)-d(x,z)|\leq d(y,z)$.

Comment: To say that the norm is continuous means that the map $x\mapsto ||x||$ is continuous. This is why we can say that if $x_n\to x$ then $||x_n||\to ||x||$. For the second part, you should show that if $\{t_n\}$ is a sequence of real numbers with $t_n\geq 1$ for all $n$ and $t_n\to t$, then $t\geq 1$. This follows from the $\varepsilon-N$ definition of convergence.

Comment: How does the continuity of the norm follow from an inequality?
Also, consider $$\lVert  x \rVert = \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} \lVert x_n \rVert = \lVert x \rVert < 1.$$ After all, why can't there be a sequence which converges to a point whose norm is less than the norm of all other points in the sequence?

Comment: @carmichael561 now I agree : we use the fact that $\|.\|$ is continuous $X \to \mathbb{R}$ (kind of tautologic since the continuity on $X$ is defined by $\|.\|$), not the "reverse triangle inequality"

Comment: The inequality shows that if $||x-y||<\varepsilon$ then $|\;||x||-||y||\;|<\epsilon$. So taking $\delta=\varepsilon$ shows that $x\mapsto ||x||$ is continuous.

Comment: So I would like to say : $\{x \in X, \|x\| \ge 1\}$ is closed by definition (since $\{x \in X, \|x\| < 1\}$ is by definition open )

Comment: Why can't there be a sequence which converges to a point whose norm is less than the norm of all other points in the sequence?

Comment: a @sequence that converges for what norm ? :D

Comment: If you have a sequence $\{t_n\}$ of real numbers with $t_n\to t$ and $t_n\geq 1$ for all $n$, then $t\geq 1$. After all, if $t<1$ then we can choose $\varepsilon>0$ small enough that $t+\varepsilon<1$, and $t_n\to t$ implies that $|t_n-t|<\varepsilon$ for large enough $n$, hence $t_n<t+\varepsilon<1$ for large enough $n$, contradiction.

Comment: Then, I think, the proof should go like this: suppose $\exists x\in V$ such that $\lVert x \rVert < 1$, and $x$ is a limit point of $S$. Then $\exists \{x_n\}$, a sequence entirely contained in $S$, such that $x_n\to x$. Then, $\forall\varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N>0$ such that $n>N$ implies $\lVert x_n-x \rVert <\varepsilon$. Choose $\varepsilon$ such that $\lVert x \rVert+\varepsilon < 1$.  Then $\left| \lVert x_n \rVert -\lVert x \rVert \right| \le \lVert x-x \rVert < \varepsilon$ implies that $\lVert x_n \rVert < \lVert x \rVert + \varepsilon < 1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @sequence: That looks good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I was in a similar trouble yesterday completing a very similar proof for the closure of a set under a normed space.

The unique that you need to focus is in prove that if for all $n$ we have that $\|x_n\|\ge 1$ and if $(x_n)\to x$ then $\|x\|\ge 1$.

This comes from the theorem that says that for converging sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$

$$y_n<x_n,\forall n\in\Bbb N\implies \lim y_n\le \lim x_n$$

and this is obviously true too if we have that $y_n\le x_n$ (we dont need the strict inequality). Then if we set as a constant sequence $y_n=w$ such that $\|w\|=1$ for all $n$ then $\lim \|y_n\|=1\le \lim\|x_n\|$.

---

Another way to prove it is characterizing a convergence sequence under it open balls, i.e. if we have that for some $(x_n)\to x$

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N:\|x_n-x\|<\epsilon,\forall n\ge N$$

then we can write too

$$\forall\epsilon>0,\exists N\in\Bbb N:x_n\in \Bbb B(x,\epsilon),\forall n\ge N$$

where $\Bbb B(x,\epsilon):=\{y\in V:\|x-y\|<\epsilon\}$. Then for any $\epsilon>0$ *almost all* points of the sequence are contained in $\Bbb B(x,\epsilon)$.

Now observe if the elements of $(\|x_n\|)$ belong almost all (or not) to some ball $\Bbb B(\|x\|,\epsilon)$ such that $\|x\|<1$.

P.S.: here *almost all* mean *all but finitely many*.

Comment: $\exists \epsilon > 0$ such that $\lVert x_n\rVert \not\in B(\lVert x \rVert, \epsilon)$ for any $n$, correct?

Comment: @sequence yes, this is the negation of convergence, for $\|x\|<1$.

Comment: Another short proof: if $\|x_n\|\ge 1$ for all $n$ then $\inf\{\|x_n\|:n\in\Bbb N\}\ge1$ by the definition of infimum.